# Get Application's Window Handles

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, handle

I'm building an app that given another app mainWindowhandle it collects information about the window state. I have no problem collecting information about child windows, but I can not access the other open windows of an application or even the menus. Is there any way of getting all window handles of an application?

Comment: Check out this working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28055461/1274092

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could do what `Process.MainWindowHandle` appears to do: use P/Invoke to call the [`EnumWindows`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumWindows.html) function, which invokes a callback method for every top-level window in the system.

In your callback, call [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowThreadProcessId.html), and compare the window's process id with `Process.Id`; if the process ids match, add the window handle to a list.

Answer (score 11):

First, you'll have to get the windowhandle of the application's mainwindow.

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

 IntPtr hWnd = (IntPtr)FindWindow(windowName, null);
```

Then, you can use this handle to get all childwindows:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwndParent, EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

private List<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)  
{  
    List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();  
    GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);  
    try  
    {  
         EnumWindowProc childProc = new EnumWindowProc(EnumWindow);  
         EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));  
    }  
    finally  
    {  
         if (listHandle.IsAllocated)  
               listHandle.Free();  
    }  
    return result;  
}
```

Comment: Mez the problem isn't getting child windows, I can do that easily, what I can't do is get to other windows besides mainWindow and its childs...

Comment: This works for any window, also for windows not belonging to the own application. Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: From where comes `EnumWindowProc`?

Comment: Add in a declaration for it:

private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

Comment: EnumWindowProc childProc = new EnumWindowProc(EnumWindow);
this get an error

Answer (score 2):

```
    public void GetWindowHandles()
    {
        List<IntPtr> windowHandles = new List<IntPtr>();

        foreach (Process window in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            window.Refresh();

            if (window.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero) 
            {
                windowHandles.Add(window.MainWindowHandle);
            }
        }
    }
```

Read [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle?view=net-5.0) as to why we call the refresh method and check if the pointer is zero