# Block closing WPF window (from a different thread) if OpenFileDialog is open

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

To clear things up before you mention the most obvious choice, I am already calling ShowDialog and not the Show method!!!

I would like to block the close (invoked from a different thread) off an WPF window if a OpenFileDialog is open.

Here is the code I have (reduced to show my problem):

```
public class FooWindow : Window
{
    public FooWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Closing += OnClosing;    
    }

    public void OpenDialogAndCloseMe()
    {
        var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        Thread th = new Thread(() => CloseMe());
        th.Start();

        ofd.ShowDialog(this);
    }

    public void CloseMe()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); //give the OpenFileDialog time to pop up...

        //since this method gets called from a different thread invoke it...
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.Close());
    }

    private void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //check if OpenFileDialog is still open and block the close...
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is the OnClosing part, how would I get the OpenFileDialog (or any other Dialog in that case).

I have searched the web and found Win32 methods like:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumedWindow callback, ArrayList lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
```

I have tried them both but they return 0 children, any ideas what's going wrong?

Here is the full code I tried so far:

```
//replace the above OnClosing with this implementation... all 3 return false
private void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //check if OpenFileDialog is still open and block the close...
    var hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;

    if (WindowHandling.GetChildren(hWnd).Any())
        e.Cancel = true;

    if (WindowHandling.GetChildrenV2(hWnd).Any())
        e.Cancel = true;

    if (WindowHandling.GetChildrenV3(hWnd).Any())
        e.Cancel = true;
}

public static class WindowHandling
{
    private delegate bool EnumedWindow(IntPtr handleWindow, ArrayList handles);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumedWindow callback, ArrayList lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

    private static bool GetWindowHandle(IntPtr windowHandle, ArrayList windowHandles)
    {
        windowHandles.Add(windowHandle);
        return true;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IntPtr> GetChildren(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
            return Enumerable.Empty<IntPtr>();

        var x = new WindowHandleInfo(hWnd);
        return x.GetAllChildHandles();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IntPtr> GetChildrenV2(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        var windowHandles = new ArrayList();
        EnumedWindow callBackPtr = GetWindowHandle;
        EnumChildWindows(hWnd, callBackPtr, windowHandles);

        return windowHandles.OfType<IntPtr>();
    }
    public static IEnumerable<IntPtr> GetChildrenV3(IntPtr hParent)
    {
        var result = new List<IntPtr>();
        var ct = 0;
        var maxCount = 100;
        var prevChild = IntPtr.Zero;

        while (true && ct < maxCount)
        {
            var currChild = FindWindowEx(hParent, prevChild, null, null);
            if (currChild == IntPtr.Zero)
                break;

            result.Add(currChild);
            prevChild = currChild;
            ++ct;
        }

        return result;
    }

    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363167/how-can-i-get-the-child-windows-of-a-window-given-its-hwnd
    private class WindowHandleInfo
    {
        private delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr lParam);

        private readonly IntPtr _mainHandle;

        public WindowHandleInfo(IntPtr handle)
        {
            _mainHandle = handle;
        }

        public IEnumerable<IntPtr> GetAllChildHandles()
        {
            var childHandles = new List<IntPtr>();

            var gcChildhandlesList = GCHandle.Alloc(childHandles);
            var pointerChildHandlesList = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gcChildhandlesList);

            try
            {
                var childProc = new EnumWindowProc(EnumWindow);
                var x = EnumChildWindows(this._mainHandle, childProc, pointerChildHandlesList);
                if (x == false)
                {
                    var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                gcChildhandlesList.Free();
            }

            return childHandles;
        }

        private static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            var gcChildhandlesList = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(lParam);

            if (gcChildhandlesList.Target == null)
                return false;

            var childHandles = gcChildhandlesList.Target as List<IntPtr>;
            if (childHandles != null)
                childHandles.Add(hWnd);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All this trouble to find back a Window you created yourself? How about keeping track of that `ofd` variable at the class scope?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I wanted to make this example simple its not sooo easy in my real live code. Talking about different processes working with window handles like all over the place, I just simple don't know if or if not something is open. I also don't even need to be the caller of the openfiledialog someone could get the handle of my window and open a System.Windows.Forms dialog and pass this handle to the ShowDialog method, or use WindowInteropHandler to set owner randomly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this with a boolean value tracking if it's open or not:

```
bool dialogOpen = false;

public void OpenDialogAndCloseMe()
{
    var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

    Thread th = new Thread(() => CloseMe());
    th.Start();

    dialogOpen = true;
    ofd.ShowDialog(this);
    dialogOpen = false;
}


private void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //check if OpenFileDialog is still open and block the close...
    if(dialogOpen)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid this "solution" might popup, seems like my example code is too easy for ya guys, gona try to be more specific why this isn't a good solution for me tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, you get answers on the question you ask. Not the on the ones you should have asked.