# How can I Enumerate All childwindow handle according to process id?

Tags: c++

I enumerated all process in a system. Now I am trying to enumerate all child windows according to a specific window. By the following step I can get the process id. Now, how can I get the main window handle(parent Window Handle) and child window handle for the particular handle?

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |PROCESS_VM_READ, TRUE, processID );
```

Comment: it is enumwindows not enumchildwindows

Comment: once you have the HWND of the top window it is _really_ easy to get child windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363167/how-can-i-get-the-child-windows-of-a-window-given-its-hwnd

Comment: so the flow will be like this Enumprocess->EnumWindows->EnumChildWindowProcess correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use EnumWindows for enumerate all top level windows and EnumChildWindows to enumerate the child windows