# Find child window by class

Tags: c#, winapi

I can't get the "Edit" field handle when selecting a photo in a third-party application.

Spy++ shows everything correctly, but `FindWindow` fails. I can get the handle of the window itself, the parent. I assume I need to look for child windows. I can get some handles with `GetWindow` but but it's not clear what they are. The window title is empty. `FindWindowEx` doesn't work at all, returns 0. I indicate it like this:

```cs
IntPtr hwndchild = (hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, null, "Edit")
```

[image]

Comment: You are probably looking for [EnumChildWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows).

Comment: If that invalid line of C# code is supposed to represent the parameters to `FindWindowEx`, then the class is the third parameter, not the fourth.

Comment: [FindWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) - *Retrieves a handle to the **top-level** window*.. you have to enumerate children to get lower-level window as on screenshot.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Ok, i know, but how get child-handle by class?

Comment: Call [GetClassName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclassname) for each handle returned, and compare with what you are looking for. Note that there'll typically be multiple child windows of the same class.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the screenshot you provided, and using just the `FindWindow/Ex()` functions, you can get the HWND of the Edit control like this:

```cs
IntPtr hwndDlg = FindWindow(null, "Choose an image");
IntPtr hwndCBEx = FindWindowEx(hwndDlg, IntPtr.Zero, "ComboBoxEx32", null);
IntPtr hwndCB = FindWindowEx(hwndCBEx, IntPtr.Zero, "ComboBox", null);
IntPtr hwndEdit = FindWindowEx(hwndCB, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
```

However, once you have the HWND to the ComboBoxEx control, the *correct* way to get the HWND of its Edit control is to use the [`CBEM_GETEDITCONTROL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cbem-geteditcontrol) message:

```cs
const int CBEM_GETEDITCONTROL = 1031;
IntPtr hwndDlg = FindWindow(null, "Choose an image");
IntPtr hwndCBEx = FindWindowEx(hwndDlg, IntPtr.Zero, "ComboBoxEx32", null);
IntPtr hwndEdit = SendMessage(hwndCBEx, CBEM_GETEDITCONTROL, 0, 0);
```

Note, for a standard ComboBox control (which you can get from a ComboBoxEx control using the [`CBEM_GETCOMBOCONTROL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cbem-getcombocontrol) message), you can use the [`CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-getcomboboxinfo) message or the [`GetComboBoxInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcomboboxinfo) function. The HWND of the Edit control is returned in the `COMBOBOXINFO.hwndItem` field.

Comment: Thank you, the best simple solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a child window of a parent you should use EnumChildWindows. The following is C++ code but could be pinvoked easily: you can marshal delegates as function pointers for the callback.

```
std::vector<HWND> FindChildrenByClass(HWND parent, const std::string& target_class)
{
    struct EnumWndParam {
        std::vector<HWND> output;
        std::string target;
    } enum_param;

    enum_param.target = target_class;

    EnumChildWindows(
        parent,
        [](HWND wnd, LPARAM lparam) -> BOOL {
            auto param = reinterpret_cast<EnumWndParam*>(lparam);
            char class_name[512];
            GetClassName(wnd, class_name, 512);
            if (param->target == class_name)
                param->output.push_back(wnd);
            return TRUE;
        },
        reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&enum_param)
    );

    return enum_param.output;
}

int main()
{
    auto windows = FindChildrenByClass( reinterpret_cast<HWND>(0x0061024A), "Edit");
    for (auto wnd : windows) {
        std::cout << std::hex << wnd << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note in the above that I *do not* recursively call FindChildrenByClass in the callback lambda. This is not a mistake. EnumChildWindows already performs this recursion. It runs over a parent window's children and grand children, etc., out of the box without you having to specify this behavior or implement it.

Answer (score -5):

Like someone already assumed. Try the EnumChildWindow method.
Here is an complete sample already on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363167/how-can-i-get-the-child-windows-of-a-window-given-its-hwnd)